# How to know when there is network blip at the time of download using ReadableByteChannel and FileOutputStream?

Tags: java

I would like to download a file of size 50MB using the below code and it works fine. But it was stopped when there is a network blip.

How to know when there is problem at the time of download

```
 URL finalURL = new URL(downloadURL);
 ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(finalURL.openStream());
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localPath);
 fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it just stopped and didn't threw an `IOException`?

Comment: It is not throwing any exception

Answer (score 0):

Surround it with try catch? Catch an IOException?